# How to get text in my new member using JCL

Tags: member, mainframe, jcl

I have to make a new member in a JCL. This isn't a problem:
My code:

```
//STEP1 EXEC PGM=IEBGENER
//SYSUT1 DD *
//SYSUT2 DD DISP=(NEW,KEEP),UNIT=SYSALLDA,DSN=name.JCL4(MEMBER),
            SPACE=(CYL,(1,1,45)),
            VOL=SER=DMTU01
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN DD DUMMY
/*
```

But I want that my MEMBER1 contains text.
So when I go in JCL4 and I press an e (edit) before MEMBER, I want to see some text like 'Hallo'. Can someone help me to explain how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are creating a **new member** in an **existing** JCL dataset, Try:

```
//STEP1   EXEC PGM=IEBGENER
//SYSUT1  DD  *
   Hello
/*
//SYSUT2  DD DSN=name.JCL4(MEMBER),DISP=(SHR,KEEP)
//SYSIN DD DUMMY
/*
```

The Disp refers to the **dataset** and not the **member**. so if the dataset already exists, you do not need to create it !!.

---

If you want create a **new** JCL **dataset** and a **member** at the same time,
the JCL should be like (where you **catlg** the dataset)

```
//STEP1   EXEC PGM=IEBGENER
//SYSUT1  DD  *
   Hello
/*
//SYSUT2  DD DSN=name.JCL4(MEMBER),DISP=(NEW,CATLG),
//           UNIT=SYSALLDA,     should this be sysda ???
//           SPACE=(CYL,(1,1,45)),
//           VOL=SER=DMTU01
//SYSIN DD DUMMY
/*
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine for me, but when I try to combine it, it doesn't work. So I want to make the new JCL when I'm making the first member, but I also want to create a new member in that existing JCL in the same JCL. I've done this:

Comment: If you combine the 2 Steps; the create needs to come first. You probably should ask a new question with the JCL and the error message